# (C# or Java) get output sound to equalizer

Tags: java, c#, audio, equalizer

Is there a way to get the output sound from my PC using C# or Java. After this i need to get the volume for the lows, mids and highs of the sound. Is this possible and how?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Not in it's entirety, no, but if I were tackling it I would break it down into smaller, more digestible chunks of specific technical issues (then post on SO if needs be). You should try that first.

Comment: Actually @DeeMac is trying to say that 'post what you have tried ':)

Comment: @dasrohith - not really, I'm telling him this problem is too big, which makes it unsuitable for SO. Even if he has shown what he has tried this needs breaking down a bit.

Comment: The problem with breaking it down is that i might have one API that gets the sound and a completely other API that will try to equalize the sound. I put it into one post to get one that will do both but if you know a API that can get the computers output sound or an EQ API the please post it. I will mark it as solved if works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use opensource project [Jfuge](http://www.jfugue.org/) for performing this. Please note its **Java** Open source

Comment: This looks like it's for making music. I need something to get the sound from the system and turn it into a equalizer.